# Using \mathsmaller in math display mode makes the character appear to the right of the symbol instead of below it

Tags: math-mode, math-operators, displaystyle

I am trying to use `\prod` in math display mode, but the default size is larger than I want, so I am using `\mathsmaller` from the `relsize` package to reduce the size. An unwanted side effect of this, however, is that it causes the limits of the product to appear on the right side of it instead of above and below. Is there any way to make the symbol smaller while keeping the limits above and below the product symbol?

Comment: Hi Muaz, [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Could you provide a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)? You can use backticks to edit your post to render inline code snippets :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know the package you mention and you didn't provide an example but using `\mathop` around the construction will revert to the operator limits positioning.

```
 \mathop{\mathsmaller.....}_0^n
```

Comment: Use `\mathop{\mathsmaller\prod}_{..}^{..}` from [`relsize`](http://ctan.org/pkg/relsize). The output is similar to that of `\textstyle\prod` via `\DeclareMathOperator*`.

Comment: I am still new so cannot post images. thanks

Answer (score 3):

For consistency, define a new math operator to be set in `\textstyle` using [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)'s `\DeclareMathOperator*`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\DeclareMathOperator*{\sProd}{\textstyle\prod}
\usepackage{relsize}% http://ctan.org/pkg/relsize
\begin{document}
\[
  \prod_{i=1}^{\infty}\ %\frac{1}{i} =
  {\mathsmaller \prod_{i=1}^{\infty}}\ %\frac{1}{i} =
  \sProd_{i=1}^{\infty} %\frac{1}{i}
\]
\end{document}​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```